# Commenting in real time using getstream

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

I'm working with the js/node api of getstream and I'm trying to add a realtime feature to the comments on the activities, but I'm receiving a 403 error, displaying I dont have  permission.

I've tried using targetFeeds: '[timeline:userid]' but it wrecks the application.

Also I tried to use the notification feed as in the documents is being used, and I can set targetFeeds like this: '[notification:userid]' which obviously is not the desired thing to do because this will cause that every message on different activities of this user will be shown on the callback.

```
client.reactions.add("comment", activityId, {
      "text": newComment,
      "profileImage": 'https://i.pravatar.cc/300',
      "timestamp": date,
      "from": userId,
      "id": foreignId,
    },
    {targetFeeds: [`CommentsFeed:${activityId}`]});
```

And the response of the 403 is the next one:

```
{
  code: 17
  detail: "You don't have permission to do this"
  duration: "0.18ms"
  exception: "NotAllowedException"
  status_code: 403
}
```

The expected result is not having the 403, that will trigger the callback I implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default permission settings allow users to only write activities to their own feeds; in this case you are adding an activity to `CommentsFeed:${activityId}`.

You can request support (support@getstream.io) to whitelist this for you app(s). Just make sure to mention this case and include your applications.

Comment: So there is'nt a way to give a token with read/write access to ```*```

Comment: I would not recommend it but you can ask support to set that up for your app(s) if you want that.

Comment: The white list in the feed was the solution. Thanks